# ImportXML with Index() function return wrong value

Tags: function, indexing, google-sheets

I have a problem with a function on Google Sheet.
I wrote this in a cell :

> =index(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/power-ledger/";"//span[@data-currency-price]");1)

It should print the same value which is on this website : [click here](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/power-ledger/)
but instead of that it shows a complete different value. I don't get it, where am I wrong?

Comment: Can we ask you about the output that you expect and the value that you currently retrieve?

Comment: Yes, I expect the USD value shown on the website (currently $1.05) but I have with the function I made the number : 42859). It's tottaly wrong so I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, your function retrieves 1.04 now. This is not the same with your result. So can you try this?

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/power-ledger/","//span[@id='quote_price']/@data-usd")
```

This function retrieves `#####` from following HTML.

```
<span id="quote_price" data-currency-price data-usd="#####">
```

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: I tried your function and I get an error : "Formula analyze error" something like that.. Thanks anyway for your help !

Comment: @OFFEN I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Now I retrieve 1.04642 using this. My environment may be different from yours. So can you share your sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Here it is : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSwKzEceDgYOdHpTl7lByXLtfSL6etErVV2Zw7wYnqjVAedbptRJ-1IUrLBeHymbQj_bPc8I5yxWpIB/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true ;)

Comment: If I delete the index() function I can get 1.05 but I get "USD" too. So it's weird.

Comment: @OFFEN How about this?
 ``=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/power-ledger/";"//span[@class='text-large2']")``

Comment: "The imported content is empty"

Comment: @OFFEN That returns 1.07.

Comment: So you're right, I think the cause of the problem is my environment.

Comment: I'm not on Github :/ But it doesn't matter I give up, I will find another solution. But I thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Man, it's just crazy, now the value is above 1.14 and it works.... My problem is solved but I don't understand how...

Comment: =index(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/power-ledger/";"//span[@data-currency-price]");1). But now it doesn't work anymore. The problem seems to be the value itself. Sometimes, it works and sometimes not. I will sleep and see that tomorrow...